# What are the main physical consequences of supergravity?

Tags: cosmology, supersymmetry, supergravity

String theory in some limit becomes supergravity.

This is the super generalisation of gravity where instead of taking the Poincare symmetry as the local symmetry of spacetime we take the super-Poincare group.

This rather sounds like a *formal* generalisation of gravity. For example, we can *formally* generalise Newtonian mechanics to work in any number of spatial dimensions, nevertheless there are only three spatial dimensions.

One of the remarkable consequences of Einsteins rethinking of gravity is how it *changed* and *developed* our understanding of physical concepts of space, time, energy and mass whilst introducing new mathematical techniques into the physicists armoury - manifolds, tensors, curvature and the like; nevertheless, the latter would not have had the impact they had were it not for the physical reconceptualising.

This appears to be remarkably difficult to find out for something as basic as supergravity where mathematical techniques appear to take front stage. Thus,

**Q. What are the main physical consequences of super-gravity? And I am emphasise here in terms of space, time, energy, momenta and inertia - the basic physical furniture of physics?**

Answer (score 1):

The immediate consequence is the doubling (or quadrupling, etc., depending on the number of supersymmetries N) of particles because of supersymmetry.

Another important consequence is restrictions on possible Lagrangians, in particular, scalar potentials. These restrictions become more and more severe for larger N.

Also quantum (perturbative) behavior of supergravity is somewhat better than that of general relativity.